# How to use different AWS accounts on Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have a Jenkins instance that currently deploys to a develop account, but we now have a prod account that I would like to deploy from on the same instance. I have all the AWS creds in the config file, and currently injecting the environment variable "AWS_PROFILE" into a job with the prod creds name, but it's not connecting to the correct account. Is what I want possible?

Comment: Depends on what plugin are you using. This one is providing with such functionality - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JClouds+Plugin. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin this one - not.

Comment: I'm trying to run integration tests against AWS resources and using the aws CLI to copy to S3.